# After update to GRJ90 I can no longer use WiFi hot-spot

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-nexus-s, tethering, sprint

My phone updated to GRJ90 about two weeks ago and now I can no longer use WiFi hot-spot or USB tethering. When I try, my 3G connection is dropped. After disconnecting and waiting a few minutes, it comes back up. I used to be able to tether before the update. How can I bypass this, or stop the 3G from disconnecting when tethering. Sprint tells me that I need to pay for a hot-spot plan for $30, but there has to be a way around this besides rooting my phone and putting Cyanogen on it.

Phone: Nexus S 4G from Google
Carrier: Sprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sprint tells me that I need to pay for a hot-spot plan for $30, but there has to be a way around this besides rooting my phone and putting Cyanogen on it.

[Sprint clamped down and disabled the previously free built-in tethering with the latest update](http://phandroid.com/2011/07/26/nexus-s-4g-2-3-5-ota-kills-free-tethering-flashable-version-available-for-rooted-users/). If you want USB tethering you can try [PDANet](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/), but wifi tethering will almost certainly require you to root, as it does on other devices.

Even with root, you don't necessarily need to use CyanogenMod if you don't want to, though; you could just as easily install a free tethering app ([one example](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/&rct=j&q=android%20wifi%20tether&ei=6ONbTqPTJ83OgAfP5rCEDA&usg=AFQjCNFzfi3e8gdSz-VeUervA-3nhoOPHw&sig2=Y7gvxHsXOSpq3MZmswF8lw&cad=rja)). This has been covered here a lot, in fact, so you might want to take a look at any wifi tethering apps noted in other questions.

See also: [Is there a way to enable WiFi-tethering without root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253/is-there-a-way-to-enable-wifi-tethering-without-root-access)